# What are the various SW:TOR servers named after?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

In WoW, Blizzard named their servers after prominent characters or groups. I had expected that SW:TOR would be the same way.

Now, I'm no starwars neophyte, but I don't recognize half the terms that make up the server list.

"Space Slug"? "Naddist Rebels"? "Bondar Crystal"? "Veela"? (Trying to Google that last one got me a list of Harry Potter references...)

Is there a generic solution to figure out what my server is named after? Where is Bioware getting these names?

Comment: Several are from characters or places from Knights of the Old Republic lore, or the recent novels that lead up to SWTOR like Deception and Revan. Like "The Twin Spears", "Fat Man", etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the servers that I reconize are taken from the various expanded universe novels and graphic novels (a few refrences to kotor as well). I assumed the few I don't are taken from the same place, although I wouldn't put a little "that sounds like star wars, right?" past them.

As for a specific method for finding out about one particular name, you could either read every single star wars licensed property, or you could do a specific search on [wookiepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page), who does a pretty good job of keeping track for you.

Comment: Some of the server names are just silly.  The server my character is on is named "Space Slug" which my friends and I ran with, founding the "Cult of the Space Slug" guild. Rubat Crystal, a crafting ingredient in KOTOR, is the name of another.